# .net MAUI - Hide keyboard when SearchBar lost focus

Tags: maui, window-soft-input-mode, soft-input-panel

Here is a `ContentPage` with a `SearchBar` and a `ListView`.
`ListView` is updating as the user type in the `SearchBar`.

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <SearchBar Placeholder="Rechercher..." TextChanged="..." x:Name="searchBar"/>
    <ListView ItemTapped="..." HasUnevenRows="True" SelectionMode="None" x:Name="ListView_Abonnes"
          ItemsSource="..." ItemTemplate="..." Refreshing="..." IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True">
</StackLayout>
```

The problem is that when the user scoll the ListView results, the keyboard does not close automatically.
Please, somebody know how to do if we want that the keyboard close when user scoll the ListView ?

Thanks you

I already try to catch gesture recognizer on the `StackLayout`, and I also try to catch the scrolled event on the `ListView`, but that has no effect because the `ListView` scrolled() event is called when updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the [Scrolled event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview#detect-scrolling) and then hide the Soft Input Keyboard if it is currently visible using [Maui Community toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/extensions/keyboard-extensions).

Here's the code snippet for your reference:

**XMAL:**

```
 <StackLayout> 
     <SearchBar Placeholder="Rechercher..." TextChanged="SearchBar_TextChanged" x:Name="searchBar"/>
        <ListView x:Name="ListView_Abonnes" HasUnevenRows="True" SelectionMode="None"  IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"  Refreshing="ListView_Refreshing" Scrolled="ListView_Abonnes_Scrolled">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" >
                    </TextCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
private void ListView_Abonnes_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e) 
{
     searchBar.HideKeyboardAsync(CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Comment: Thanks You. But unfortunatly the list is scrolled when type in search bar. So with that method, keyboard is closing each time we type a char in searchbar

Comment: @Mickaël After typing in the SearchBar, the keyboard would close, if you want it to show again, you may need to click the SearchBar again to get it foucsed to show the keyboard.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT thanks for your post linking "Hide Keyboard" (a.k.a. soft input) to the [CommunityToolkit.Maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/) NuGet. I was totally unaware of this IP. What a great find!